# Disable row click in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, onclick

I want to disable a row click for the rows based on the flag value set in the columns
And the rest of the rows should be clickable and also between certain columns

The first two rows that has true should be unclickable. However, the rest of the rows should be clickable from column 1-5.

Here is the  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mEbUG/)

Comment: Please also post the **relevant** code here.

Comment: nothing is clickable for me in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract the `.text()` of the last cell in the row and test it:

```
$('#table tr').find('td:gt(0):lt(5)').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text() != "true") {
        alert("hello");
    }
})​;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mEbUG/2/

Alternatively, you can `.filter` out the undesirable cells before calling `.on("click")`:

```
$('#table tr').find('td:gt(0):lt(5)').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text() != "true");
}).on('click', function() {
    alert("hello");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mEbUG/12/

Comment: I have an image in that column instead of true/false. I am using ui-icon ui-icon-close. I need to disable for these rows, how do I check if its not text ? Please see the edited link http://jsfiddle.net/mEbUG/15/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly. You only want rows with no "true" cell, to be clickable? Or do you want each cell to be clickable, but not the cells with "true"?

Here is an example that makes the rows clickable only if there is no cell with the word "true" in them:

```
var hasTrueCell = function(cells) {

    for (var x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {

        if (cells[x].innerHTML == "true")
            return true;

    }        

    return false;

}

var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");

for (var x = 0; x < rows.length; x++) {

    if (!hasTrueCell(rows[x].childNodes))
        rows[x].onclick = function() {         

            alert("hello");    

        }        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED** (after comments)

Now, this should work.

```
$('#table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:contains("true")').length === 0;
}).click(function() {
    alert("hello");
});​​
```

​
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YUetH/2)

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: This approach fails if the string "true" appears anywhere else in the row -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/P3AVP/1/

Comment: so true. I must select `td` instead. Edited

Comment: Now it filters out cells that contain "true", but not the entire row.

Comment: And he wants that when anyone of the `td` is `true`, the whole `tr` should be unclickable . Right ?

Comment: @Jashwant yes, the whole row should be unclickable based on the value in column

Comment: Edited my answer. If that dont work, I think, I need a good sleep :)

Comment: @Jashwant: Thanks! Its working! I have a change in my problem. Instead of true I have "edit" text in the first two rows and rest of the rows its edit hyperlink. How to make this work ? see the updated link http://jsfiddle.net/mEbUG/16/

Comment: If I am getting it right, this should solve the problem,

http://jsfiddle.net/mEbUG/17/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table tr').find('td:gt(0):lt(5)').click(function(){if($(this).text()!="true")alert(1)})​
```